# Create plan on stripe through laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I want to create a plan from my application on stripe. The scenario is that users are charged with different prices as recurring payments. So, that is why I want to create plan for each user.

I am using **laravel 5** and using `"laravel/cashier": "~5.0"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

laravel/cashier just doesn't have this functionality baked in.  You aren't out of luck though as it is easy to just use Stripe's API which should be downloaded as a dependency in your vendor folder.  If not you can just download it with composer.

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php 2.*
```

You can use it with

```
use \Stripe\Plan;

Plan::create(array(
  "amount" => 2000,
  "interval" => "month",
  "name" => "Amazing Gold Plan",
  "currency" => "usd",
  "id" => "gold")
);
```

You can read more here - https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_plan

Comment: may I ask you to take a look at a l Stripe rekated question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238551/stripe-cannot-create-a-plan ?

Answer (score 7):

For latest cashier and stripe-php versions few thing need to be changed.

My cashier version is 7.0 (`"laravel/cashier": "~7.0"`) and **it automatically installs stripe-php 5**. But some parameters has changed from stripe api. So this code will be working,

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_your_key");

\Stripe\Plan::create(array(
  "amount" => 5000,
  "interval" => "month",
  "product" => array(
    "name" => "Bronze standard"
  ),
  "currency" => "eur",
  "id" => "bronze-standard"
));
```

And you can read more in PHP section of stripe api docs...
(https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_plan)